# Angular 2: How to create input array?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am creating template driven form by following this guide: https://angular.io/guide/forms

I need array of inputs e.g.

```
<input 
  *ngFor="let screenshot of screnshots" 
  [(ngModel)]="screenshot.id" 
  type="text" 
  name="screenshots[]" />
```

But in `{{form.value}}`, it is showing just one input value instead of multiple.

I want output of `{{form.value}}` like this : `{screenshots:[1, 2, 3]}`

> I need this only in the form of array.

is it possible to implement in such way? or what is the best solution to achieve this goal?

Comment: use a model-driven form with formarray.

Answer (score 1):

Input type text doesn't support multiple values like input type select or checkbox does, just give each input box a different name like this

```
<input 
  *ngFor="let screenshot of screnshots;let i = index" 
  [(ngModel)]="screenshot.id" 
  type="text" 
  [name]="'screenshot' + i"
```

Comment: I don't agree! Input type text definitely support multiple values with same name by adding just `[]` with the name

Comment: Very interesting